# Ansible mysql_* modules show error at first launch

Tags: linux, ansible

This is my yml file which should update system, install mysql-server, change binding and run steps from "mysql_secure_installation".

```
---
# tasks file for deploy_db
- name: Update repos
  apt:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes

- name: Install mysql
  apt:
    name:
    - mysql-server
    - python-pymysql
    - python-apt
    state: latest

- name: Autostart mysql
  service:
    name: mysql
    enabled: yes

- name: Change mysql default binding
  replace:
    path: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    regexp: '127.0.0.1'
    replace: '0.0.0.0'

- name: Reboot after initial update
  reboot:

- name: Remove the test database
  mysql_db:
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    name: test
    state: absent

- name: Remove anonymous user
  mysql_user:
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    name: ''
    state: absent
```

If I play this yml first time - Ansible shows me error:

```
TASK [deploy_db : Remove the test database] ********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [db]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is required."}
```

If I play the same file second time - everything is OK.

What do I do wrong? "python-pymysql" which is required for task "Remove the test database" is installed some steps before and there was a reboot, everything should works but it doesn't!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, correct question is a half of answer :-)
I've modified task and now everything is OK

```
  - name: Install mysql
  apt:
    name:
    - mysql-server
    - python-pymysql
    - python3-pymysql
    - python-apt
    - python3-apt
  state: latest
```